# How to print every 4th item from list in Python?

Tags: python

How to print every **4th** item from a list?

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 8):

Use a slice:

```
fourth_items = list[3::4] # ['d', 'h', 'l']
for i in fourth_items: print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Nirks's comment,I correct my answer.
the list is built-in function in python, which is not advice to use as a variable name i change it into list_test.

```
list_test = list('abcdefghijklm')
tmp = list_test[3::4]
```

and here is the different part

print in normal order:

```
for i in tmp: print i
```

or

print in reverse order :

```
while tmp: print tmp.pop()
```

Comment: `list` is not a keyword.  It is a function, and it's not advisable to use a variable called `list`, but it's not a keyword: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/keyword.py#l16 http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/keyword.py#l16

Comment: @Nirk, I think I use the pop method is not totally wrong,after all the question is print the 4th item, it doesn't limit its printing is in normal order or reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop through, increment by 4 on every iteration. You can get the length of an array in python with `len(list)`

```
index = 0 #or start at 3, pending on where you want to start
while index < len(list) :
    print list[index]
    index +=4
```